# Call controller method on button click, without a redirect (rails 2.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-2

I am new to rails, coming in from an angular background. Is there are way to have a button trigger a controller method without having the page redirect? I would also like to somehow tie input fields to controller variables without getting models involved.

What I have is a multi-page form (customer's design, not mine). On each page I want to validate user input, but I don't want to create a model for every field of what will end up being one cohesive object.

Comment: You can use ajax. Are you using ruby 2.3?  Or do you actually mean rails 2.3?

Comment: Rails 2.3 supports RJS.

Checkout what is RJS here.http://stackoverflow.com/q/459647/5076451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can call a controller action using AJAX. Just bind and ajax call on some button's `onClick` event and that's it.
   Also take a look at `remote: true` from `jQuery-ujs`
2. You can also validate fields with JS if you don't want to touch models